# Ejabberd postgreSql Connection

Tags: postgresql, ejabberd

i connected  postgreSql with ejabberd but ejabberd doesnt create tables . Is there any problem? I suppose ejabberd still using local db.

In configuraion file ejabberd.yml . must i change something else.

thanks

```
sql_type: pgsql
sql_server: "host"
sql_database: "dbName"
sql_username: "postgres"
sql_password: "password"
##
## If you want to specify the port:
sql_port: 5432
auth_method: [sql]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to manually import the database from this link [ejabberd sql](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/tree/master/sql)